# Giving read permissions for a link to a document, but not site permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site in Sharepoint Online containing documents. I would like to link to the individual documents from another external website. But I also want to restrict the access to the SP site so users cannot find or browse its contents.

Is it possible to restrict read access to the SP site while still allowing users to follow the link and read the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to share a document in the library to users with restricted read permission.

You could share the document to specific people. They will receive an email with a link, they can access the document through the link.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the people that will need to see the document beforehand.

Comment: You could use "Anyone with the link can view", copy the share link, then send the link to users you want. So there is no need to specify users before sending the link. Update the picture in the answer.

Comment: After I do "Copy link", can I then post it on a web page instead of sending it?

Comment: Yes, you can post the link in a web page for users accessing it.